# Mimic `let' statement in a macro

Tags: hy

In the following directory structure:

```
.
├── a
│  ├── 1
│  ├── 2
│  ├── 3
│  └── 4
├── b
│  ├── 5
│  ├── 6
│  ├── 7
│  └── 8
├── c
├── d
└── test.hy
```

The following code prints the wrong path:

```
(eval-and-compile (import os) (import pathlib [Path]))

(defmacro with-cwd [dir #* body]
          `(let [ cwd (.cwd Path) ]
               (try (.chdir os ~dir)
                    ~@body
                    (finally (.chdir os cwd)))))

(defmacro let-cwd [dir vars #* body] `(let ~vars (with-cwd ~dir ~@body)))

(setv a (/ (. (Path __file__) parent) "a"))

(let-cwd a [ b (/ a.parent "b") ] (print f"Hello from {(.cwd Path)}!\n") (print (.resolve b)))
```

It is supposed to print the following:

```
Hello from /home/shadowrylander/with-cwd-test/a!

/home/shadowrylander/with-cwd-test/b
```

While it is instead printing:

```
Hello from /home/shadowrylander/with-cwd-test/a!

/home/shadowrylander/with-cwd-test/a/b
```

Why is `b` not properly assigned when doing `(quasiquote (let ~vars (with-cwd ~dir ~@body)))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug (https://github.com/hylang/hy/issues/2318), although it has to do with `__file__` and is unrelated to `let` or macros. Remember, when you run into trouble, simplify your problematic code as much as you can, so you can figure out what's going on.

Comment: Got it; should I accept this answer now, or when the issue is resolved?

Comment: @ShadowRylander It looks to me like it answers your question and hence it should be accepted.